# devise_saml_authenticatable response does not contain attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, saml-2.0

I'm in the process of trying to understand SSO, SAML, and federated identity management concepts. Right now I'm trying to authenticate with my app using [devise_saml_authenticatable](https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable) as SP; and SSOCircle as an IDP. I am getting a saml_response with nil attributes, looking at the gem code, I see that it might have to do with saml_config having no attributes in the consumer service. My guess is that it has to do with not having a [`config/idp.yml`](https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable/blob/b4e6ed56a766a7489cebe4852033900419454784/lib/devise_saml_authenticatable/saml_config.rb) file. Does anyone know how this `idp.yml` file should look like, what it should contain? I cannot find it in the repo documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I finally fixed it:

1) I realized that the SAML response contained a NoAuthnContxt status so I had to change my saml_config authnetication context to

```
# config/devise.rb
settings.authn_context = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password"
```

2) After this I succesfully got attributes in the response SAML but the indentifier keys were diff from the ones in `attributes.yml` I had to change them.

```
# config/attribute-map.yml

# "urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:uid": "uid"
# "urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:email": "email"
# "urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:name": "last_name"
# "urn:mace:dir:attribute-def:givenName": "first_name"

"EmailAddress": "email"
"LastName": "last_name"
"FirstName": "first_name"
```

Comment: My SSOCircle response DOES include the `AuthnContext`, yet the Devise SAML plugin tries to use the `NameID` property of the response as my user's email address. Neither the stock, example of attribute-map.yml, nor your edit, can seem to remap the `EmailAddress` field to the user object's `email` field.

Answer (score 0):

The [usage section](https://github.com/apokalipto/devise_saml_authenticatable#usage) of the README has the configuration for the gem. The `saml_config` is filled out in the `config.saml_configure` section, which just gives you the `RubySaml::Settings` object to configure (as described in the [ruby-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml#the-initialization-phase) documentation).

So you'll want a file called `config/initializers/devise.rb` with:

```
config.saml_configure do |settings|
  settings.assertion_consumer_service_url = "http://localhost:3000/users/saml/auth"
  # more consumer configuration here
end
```